# Expected value and Variance of a stochastic time integral of a deterministic variable (Standard Brownian motion)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Given a Standard Brownian motion  $(B_t)_{t\in\mathbf{R}_{+}}$, define:

$$E(e^{\int_0^tudB_u})=?$$
$$ Var(e^{\int_0^tudB_u})=?$$

---

I started off assuming (!) that $X_t=$ $\int_0^tudB_u \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$; so that I could apply:

$E(e^{X_t})=\int_Re^{X_t}.(pdf) dx = e^{(\mu+\frac[2\sigma^2)}$

And went on to find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of $X_t$:

1) $E(X_t)=E(\int_0^tudB_u)$

2)Since $X_t$ has no drift, and only a diffusion term, it should be a Martingale
 assuming (!) that

$E(X_t)^2<\infty$ (is bounded)

Which is since:

$E(X_t)=E(\int_0^tudB_u)^2 = E(\int_0^tu^2dt) = (\frac{t^3}{3}) < \infty$

So since it is a Martingale and $B_0=0$:

3)$E(X_t)=E(\int_0^tudB_u)=0$

4) $Var(X_t)=E(X_t^2) - [E(X_t)]^2$$= E(\int_0^tudB_u)^2-0$ $=(\frac{t^3}{3})$

5)At this point I can state:

$$X_t=\int_0^tudB_u \sim N(0,\frac{t^3}{3})$$

and apply

$E(e^{\int_0^tudB_u})=e^{0+\frac{t^3}{6}}$

6) For the variance:

$Var(e^{X_t})=E(e^{2N(0; \frac{t^3}{3}})-[E(e^{X_t})]^2 = e^{0+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{t^3}{3}} -[e^{0+\frac{t^3}{6}}]^2$

---

PS: Fixed thanks to comments

Comment: What do you mean by $N(0,\frac{t^3}{3})^2 = 2N(0,\frac{t^3}{3})$?

Comment: just brought down the power and multiplied the normal's mu and sigma for it. not sure if correct tho. That's more like a Chi-square.

Comment: Yes, exactly, squared normal random variables are Chi-square distributed. However, (6) is not correct anyway. Note that $(e^{x^2}) = e^{2x}$ and *not* $(e^x)^2 = e^{x^2}$ (... or how do you arrive otherwise at the expression $e^{X_t^2}$?)

Comment: sorry, you're right. Editing now. Changed the reasoning at point 6 but now sure if it is right now.

Comment: No, it is not. Neither is $\mathbb{E}e^{2X_t}=0$ nor $\left( \mathbb{E}e^{X_t} \right)^2 = \frac{t^9}{6}.$